# Configure Jackson to ignore everything but class fields/members

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, jackson2

I have a Spring Boot `2.3.2.RELEASE` WebFlux application. I have some JPA entities that are returned as part of the RESTful API responses.

The problem is that as I add methods (that exposes behavior) to these JPA entities, those return types/values are also being sent back, and I would like to avoid that.

Basically, what I'm looking for is to configure Jackson in such a way to only (de)serialize the class fields/members and anything annotated with `@JsonProperty`. I can also go with the approach of ignoring everything by default, and placing `@JsonProperty` on the members that I want to (de)serialize.

Note also:

- Those classes have no setters, and usually there is no constructor (except for the required no-arguments one). They used a builder most of the times.
- I know I can just annotate those methods with `@JsonIgnore`, but there will be a lot of those, so I wonder if there is another solution that includes only the fields/members (of the classes) and anything annotated with `@JsonProperty`.

Answer (score 0):

The possibilities depend on the actual code you have but you could check out **visibility**. You could configure your `ObjectMapper` like:

```
om.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
om.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.GETTER, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);
```

Then with class like below serialization would be done as stated in comments:

```
public static class TestClass {
    @Getter // getter is generated but ignored
            // because visibility for GETTER is NONE
    // still serialized because visibility for FIELD is ANY
    private String fieldThatShouldBeSerialized = "It is OK to serialize me :)";
    // not serialized because visibility for GETTER is NONE
    public String getMethodThatShouldNotBeSerialized() {
        return "It is NOT OK to serialize me :(";
    }
    @JsonProperty // serialized because explicitly asked (not auto)
    public String methodThatShouldBeSerialized() {
        return "It is OK to serialize me also :)";
    }
    @JsonProperty // serialized because explicitly asked (not auto)
                  // even it is a "getter"
    public String getAnotherMethodThatShouldBeSerialized() {
        return "It is OK to serialize me also :)";
    }

}
```